# How to set indicators for a string value in ssrs report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

i have SSRS report. Here i have an column named "Confirmed", if the value of this column is "Confirmed" then indicator will show green light. But i cannot set the condition for string value in Indicator's expression. How can i do it. Please help me.

Comment: iif(ReportItems!Textbox1.Value = "" , Green, Red)
put your "Confirmed" column into a textbox, so you can refer to it

Answer (score 3):

Indicators can only use numerical values, but there's a couple of methods you can still use.

One would be to make a `confirmed_number` column in your dataset by using `CASE` or `DECODE`:

```
Decode(confirmed, "Confirmed", 1, 0) AS confirmed_number
```

Another would be to decode the existing `confirmed` column in the Value parameter of your Indicator:

```
=IIF(Fields!CONFIRMED.Value = "Confirmed", 1, 0)
```

Either way you have a numerical value that the Indicator can use. Set the `States Measurement Unit` to Numeric, and set the `Start` and `End` values of your green icon to 1.

---

If you want an alternative to using the indicator, you can set the `BackgroundColor` of a text box based on your `confirmed` text like in Marco's comment:

```
=IIF(Me.Value = "Confirmed", "Green", "Red")
```